# No Login Request Received at the smartfox server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, smartfoxserver

I am making a game in Unity (C#/.NET Api) using SFS 2X as the game server. When the user tries to log in, I get no trace in the log specifying that a Login Request has been made by the client-side. This is confirmed when the game doesn't notify me about sending the Login Request, I do get the trace that a session has been created which expires due to inactivity. Here's part of the server log:

```
SocketReader bitswarm.sessions.DefaultSessionManager created: { Id: 21, Type: DEFAULT, Logged: No, IP: 116.71.185.89:52914 } on Server port: 9933 <---> 52914

SocketReader bitswarm.sessions.DefaultSessionManager Session removed: { Id: 21, Type: DEFAULT, Logged: No, IP: 116.71.185.89:52914 }
```

I experience no problem in connecting on the IPads I have with me. However the problem occurs when a certain user tries to login from his/her country through his/her IPad.

I have a related question: How does the server confirms receiving a login request in the log? Does one get to know about it when the user has logged in?

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

SmartfoxServer 2X has an admin tool that shows you how many users are logged in.
For you to see them with the adim tool you have to create a Zone and a Room because the server puts the users in the room and than you are able to see them.

Sorry if I missunderstood your question but I hope this info is useful for you.